# Exception in thread "main" : unresolved compilation probl*m

Tags: java, runtime.exec

Getting error "Exeption in thread "main" java.lang.Error 'Unresolved compilation problem':

at ClassName.main(ProjectName.java:7)

this is just a test program to see how runtimes work

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        String[] s = new String[] {"C:\\Window\\SystemApps\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\MicrosoftEdge.exe", "https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"};

        runtime.exec(s);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Runtime.exec(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) throws `IOException` and you don't catch it. Thus your program does not compile.

```
try {
    runtime.exec(s);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the "correct" way to open a browser from a Java would be [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) like

```
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Now URI cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: `import java.net.URI;` - refer to Javadoc link.

Comment: And now I have an error when declaring the runner.